# Oauth and database in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, oauth-2.0

I want to use open Authentication using ember.js and then i want to push the user's details in a mysql database. How should a progress? I am new to ember.js.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, glad to have you joining the community!

Look into the `ember-simple-auth` addon initially. If that doesn't work for what you need, `torii` is also worth a look.

Also, as an FYI, the Ember community generally uses this website to look up addons, as it rates addons quite well: https://emberobserver.com/categories/authentication